# Get data from Sqlite database one at a time with Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am building an application where the user can save some information into an sqlite database. What I now want to do is be able to get the data from the sqlite database and store each row in its own string.

Note
There is only one column in the database.

Comment: What have you tried, and what happened? You probably want to build a `List<String>`...

Comment: It would be much better if you would try for yourself - read tutorials about accessing a database from Android etc - and then if you have problems, explain which bits went wrong or what you didn't understand.

Comment: you can start from here for database  http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html  an then ask doubts here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, algoritm is not difficult, just create `Cursor` and in loop you will be retrieving data from it and then save them to `List` for example.

So try this snippet of code:

```
final String SELECT_QUERY = "Select column from Table";
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
String member = null;
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(SELECT_QUERY, null);
if (c.getCount() > 0 && c.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
      member = new String(c.getString(0));
      data.add(member);
   }
   while (c.moveToNext());
}
```